# checking on two different elements for different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

My project has generated sets of HTML elements with classes. I would like to search in the sets to see if any element has the class `span1hr` next to by an element that has the class `span0hr`, then change the class from `span1hr` to `span1hrfor30mins` for each row using with the loops.

Here's a sample of what the HTML elements could look like:

```html
<div id="programe1" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_2 row2"></div>
<div id="programe2" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3 span1hr">NCIS</div>
<div id="programe3" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_4 row4 span0hr">CBS Evening News With Scott Pelley</div>
<div id="programe4" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_5 row5 span1hr">NCIS: Los Angeles</div>
<div id="programe5" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_6 row6">Person of Interest</div>
<div id="programe6" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_2 row2 span1hr">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe7" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe8" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_4 row4 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe9" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_5 row5 span1hr">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe10" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_6 row6 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe11" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_2 row2 span1hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe12" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_3 row3 span1hr">Around the World</div>
<div id="programe13" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_4 row4 span0hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe14" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_5 row5 span2hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe15" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_6 row6 span1hr">The Lead With Jake Tapper</div>
```

In this case, since `programe2` and `programe12` has a `span1hr` class, `programe3` and `programe14` has a `span0hr` class, I would like find on the sets on each `row3` with a class `span1hr` next to by `row4` with a class `span0hr` to change the class in each `row3` to change it from `span1hr` to `span1hrfor30mins` while the class `span0hr` in the `row4` remains unchanged. For other classes in the `programe7` and `programe8` that has a class 'span1hr' which don't match in the `programe2` and `programe12`, I want to ignore it.

I have tried the code like this, but it will search for every sets of `row3` in the html without checking on two different sets `row3` and `row4` to change the class.

```js
if ($('.span1hr').hasClass('row3') && $('.span0hr').hasClass('row4')) {
    $('.span1hr').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(e).hasClass('row3') && $(e).hasClass('.span1hr')) {
            $(e).attr('row3');
            $(e).removeClass('span1hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: sorry, but the format of this question hurts my eyes 8/

Comment: What about row5 where the span1hr is next to a span0hr element but after it?

Comment: please make this more readable

Comment: @j08691 I would like to ignore the `row5` where the `span1hr` is next to a span0hr because I will be using the element of `row3` to find a classes of span0hr next to span1hr. how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be even more simple than that, if I am understanding your issue correctly (admittedly, I had to read through the logic a number of times before I felt like I understood what you were looking for   :D   ).   This should work:

```
$(".row3.span1hr + .row4.span0hr").each(function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass("span1hrfor30mins").removeClass("span1hr");
});
```

That would grab all of the elements that had both the `row4` and `span0hr` classes **AND** that occurred immediately after an element with `row3` and `span1hr` classes.  Then it would step back to the first element (i.e., the `.row3.span1hr` element) using `.prev()`, add the `span1hrfor30mins` class, and remove the `span1hr` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can express the adjacency with a CSS (Sizzle) selector, and update the inner conditions:

```js
if ($('.span1hr').hasClass('row3') && $('.span0hr').hasClass('row4')) {
    $('.span1hr.row3').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($('+.span0hr.row4', e).length) {
            $(e).attr('row3');
            $(e).removeClass('span1hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
        }
    });
}
```

Fact to matter, as the iteration will not be applied if no elements were returned by the selector, you can lose the outer condition altogether:

```js
// first select all elements with both span1hr and row3 classnames 
$('.span1hr.row3').each(function (i, e) {
    // search if the adjacent sibling of the specified selector
    // is present in the context of e
    if ($('+.span0hr.row4', e).length) {
        // do whatever we like
        $(e).attr('row3');
        $(e).removeClass('span1hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
    }
});
```

See a [**live demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/REjC5/5/).

#### Further reading:

- [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) on MDN
- [`jQuery(selector [, context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) on the jQuery API reference

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i can see the red color has changed on `CBS Evening News With Scott Pelley` and `CNN Newsroom` that has a class `span0hr` with the element `row4`. I only want to input the red color on `NCIS` and `CNN Newsroom` because they has a class `span1hr` with the element `row3`. how i can do that?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson i believe i've achieved what you're looking for, see the updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help which it much appreciated. I am glad that you have helped me to solve my problem. I have give you a good rep and I have tick the answer. I hope you will return the same :)

Comment: I am glad that you have helped to solve my problem. There is one more thing I have forgotten to ask you, could you please tell me how to change the text color in each element in row3 when I want to check on the class `span1hrfor30mins` in an element `row2`? here is the jsfiddle example i am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/REjC5/6/

Comment: please post another question on the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this work work for you.

```
$('.span1hr').each(function(){
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('span0hr')) {
        $(this).removeClass('span1hr');
        $(this).addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
    }
});
```